# How to sort arrays by maximum same values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How to sort arrays by maximum same values ??

here are arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 4
    [8] => 4
    [9] => 4
    [10] => 5
)
```

What i want is to sort arrays by maximum values , so array should look

```
Array
(   
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 3
    [10] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = [3,4,2,3,2,2,3,4,5,2];

$count = [];
foreach ($arr as $a)
{
  // Count how many times each number appears and store it in an array
  // where the key is the number and the value the count.
  $count[$a] = isset($count[$a]) ? $count[$a]+1 : 1;
}

// As @drip wrote you can use 'array_count_values' instead:
// $count = array_count_values($arr);

// Sort the array in reverse order while maintaining index association.
arsort($count);

$new = [];
foreach ($count as $a => $c)
{
  // Create a new array with the values appearing as many times as counted.
  for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++)
  {
    $new[] = $a;
  }
}
```

Comment: its work like a charm thanks,  can you tell me your logic ? ^^

Comment: @user1905807 I'm not sure if it helps, but I've added some comments.

Answer (score 3):

Another one:

```
$arr = Array(2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5);

$result = array();

$count = array_count_values($arr);
arsort($count);
foreach($count as $num => $repeat ){
    for ($i = 0; $i < $repeat; $i++){
        $result[] = $num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a really easy way to do this. What I'd do is first loop through the array and count the number of occurences of each entry. After that, loop through the counting array (keys: values of original array, values: number of occurences) and then create a new array by adding each **key** to it **value** times.

Pseudo:

```
for k,v in arr
  counts[v] = (counts[v] ?? 0) + 1
end

for k,v in counts
  for i=0 to v
    sortedArray.push(k)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`usort()` allows you to have as much control over the sort as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert solution in function

```
function asorth($arr){
$result = array();
$count = array_count_values($arr);
arsort($count);
foreach($count as $num => $repeat ){
    for($i = 0; $i < $repeat; $i++){
        $result[] = $num;
    }
}
 return $result;
}
```

asorth = array sort by highest values